# How can I express a "person has a desire to do something"?

Tags: syntax

Sometimes I want to tell expressions like:

> Mrs. Honda wants to swim in the sea.

All I have in my Japanese notes is:

```
私はケータイがほしいです。(Syntax used for expressing my personal desires for an object)
本田さんはケータイをほしがっています。(Syntax used for when a third party wants/desires an object.)
子どもはアイスクリームをほしがります。(Syntax used when a group of people wants something.)
```

As is noticed above the ほしい(です) part becomes ほしがる. Does this apply when talking about what a 3rd party person wants. either is an object or an action that wants to do.

Comment: 「ほじかったいます」もタイポでは・・・？ Are you sure it was what you meant to type?　Also, アイスクウリーム-> アイスクリーム

Comment: Ekhmmm... when I said 〜がほしい instead of 〜を I meant that for every example.

Comment: You use が for ケータイ**が**ほしいです cos ほしい is an i-adjective but を for ケータイ**を**ほしがっています cos ほしがる is a verb. (I edited your examples) By the way, XXはYYをほしが**ってい**ます and XXはYYをほしが**り**ます are a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Senko Maynard (2009:172), the difference between ～たい and ～たがる is due to a distinction made between what a person directly experiences or feels and information a person has only indirect access to.

In the same way, the Kurosio Dictionary of Grammar (2014:202) says ～たがる is "used to express the wishes or desires of a third person", implying the meaning of "showing signs of s.t.". It seems like we can just tell someone/something shows signs of wanting to do something.

Comment: So the  answer to my problem is: 本田さん海で泳ぎたがります。 Right?

Comment: Yup! Or else 「本田さんは海で泳ぎたがる。」with the particle :)

Comment: `本田さんは海で泳ぎたがる` -> Usually we say 本田さんは海で泳ぎたが**ってい**る。(or 泳ぎたが**ってい**ます。 in the polite form), no?

Comment: @chocolate Indeed! I didn't pay enough attention to the structure being used mainly in the present continuous, sorry about that